# Setting up Aptana Studio 3 in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: php

Aptana initially loads for PHP (and maybe other languages) with a black background with white letters.  I have tried to reverse these and get mixed results like the code line only shows up when highlighted.  Can u point me in the right direction as searching FAQ has not helped.  Thx  John

Comment: I have never seen a software that doesn't have restore to default setting. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by going into Preferences->Aptana->Themes (or go into preferences and in the search bar type in themes)then you should see a drop down that says Aptana studio, here you can pick different theme templates and not have to customize it yourself.

Hope this helps

Comment: That was too simple!!  Thanx it has brought sanity back to my world!!  John K